# What is a word for difficult to shelf?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm trying to express that a certain item's geometric design makes it difficult to shelf, which is why it is often hanged instead. But it is not however "unshelfable".

How can I say "difficult to" in this context?
E.g.

> As seen in this copy, the cover was usually perforated to be nailed or hanged to a wall due to its unique design, which made it difficult to shelf.

---

EDIT

***Shelve***

: to place on a shelf; shelve books

[Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/shelve)

Comment: Note: the verb is "to shelve".

Comment: There are many words for things that are hard to handle, like unwieldy, unmanageable, discommodious, but afaik none relates specifically to shelving. Try a thesaurus though.

Comment: The problem may not be that shelving the package is difficult, but that the shape is asymmetrical, or without a flat bottom, or round. There was an LP in the '70s in a round record jacket - they rolled off shelves! Perhaps specify the difficulty rather than "difficult".

Comment: What exactly do you mean by shelving? Shelving something means to not accept something.

Comment: What's wrong with just saying "hard to shelve"? Why do you need to create a new word for this?

Comment: BTW..."hanged" is the past participle of the verb meaning to "put to death by noose"; the better word form in this case  is "hung". i.e. "hung on the wall" Apart from that, would _not ergonomic/unergonomic_ work?

Comment: @Lambie - To a librarian, shelving means putting returned books back in their correct places on the shelves! But I wouldn't use it with reference to storing anything else on a shelf.

Comment: Also, there is the more common metaphorical use of the word 'shelved' as in 'put to one side' See MW 3 a&b

Comment: How about "shelfishy"?

Comment: @HotLicks [groan] I  imagine that would embrace all types of egoistic/egotistic  Arthropodial behaviour?...the mind boggles.

Comment: Please add a sentence with a space for the required single word. You are requesting synonyms for both 'difficult to shelve' and 'difficult to' at the moment.

Comment: @YosefBaskin you are referring to precisely the context in which this question came up. Artaud

Comment: I find this thread rather amusing. I marked user405662's answer, @tchrist as "hard to shelf" wouldn't necessarily be true, you might technically shelf an item with ease but in a manner which is, as the answer suggests, unconducive - such as utilizing an unusual shelf or pinning it somehow.

Comment: Nearly unshelvable. Almost unshelvable. Etc.

Comment: @KateBunting Seriously? Do you imagine I don't know that? In slang, to shelve something means to not do it at present: The project was shelved. [Collins Dictionary] That said, the OP's use of shelve makes no sense. I think s/he **may mean** **put it on a shelf**. The collocation is: Hang something up or nail something up.

Comment: @Lambie - Then why didn't you say _can also mean 'not to accept something'_?

Comment: @KateBunting Ay, Katie lass, I did. :) I just didn't mention the books or retail tasks. No worries.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not clear what you're asking.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

How about recasting the sentence thus instead?

> As seen..., the unique design of the cover renders it **unconducive** to shelving.

Lexico defines **unconducive** as:

*(usually unconducive to)*

> Making a certain situation or outcome unlikely or impossible.

Comment: hang a picture on the wall, nail a picture to the wall. Ergo, shelve as a verb simply does not collocate here.